# URL() return 404 using JQuery ajax

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5.8

I'm trying to POST login using JQuery ajax but return 404 on routes/web.php. Using routes/api.php return the same.

routes/web.php

```
Route::post('dashboard/login', 'MsServiceAdvisorController@login');
```

routes/api.php

```
Route::post('ms-sa/login','MsServiceAdvisorController@login');
```

MsServiceAdvisorController@login

```
public function login(Request $request) {
    $username = $request->username;
    $password = $request->password;

    $sa = msServiceAdvisor::where('username',$username)->get();
    $loginPassword = Crypt::decryptString($sa[0]['password']);
    if ($sa->count() == 0) {
        $result[] = array(
            'status' => 'username not found'
        );
    } else {
        if ($loginPassword == $password) {
            $result[] = array(
                'status' => 'success',
                'username' => $sa[0]['username'],
                'nama' => $sa[0]['nama'],
            );
        } else {
            $result[] = array(
                'status' => 'wrong password'
            );
        }
    }

    return $result;
}
```

Jquery ajax

```
$.ajax({
  url: "{{ url('/dashboard/login') }}",
  method: "post",
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```

That code return something like this in browser console

```
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/%7B%7B%20url('/dashboard/login')%20%7D%7D 404 (Not Found)
```

Whats wrong with that? I'm new to laravel.

Comment: In which file did you put that Ajax call? To use blade syntax you have to store it in a blade file in the Laravel views

Comment: @mdexp I put Ajax call inside login.php in laravel view. The website working fine with web.php route, but Ajax didn't work.

Comment: @mdexp please look at what browser console error. That is the url in AJAX, is it true url('dashboard/login') will shows like this %7B%7B%20 between that?

Comment: Please also add defination of this `'MsServiceAdvisorController@login'` method ?

Comment: @ViperTecPro I updated my post with MsServiceAdvisorController@login. The API is up and running for android apps, and works fine.

Comment: ohhk well when you're calling ajax you should return with response json like this `return response()->json($result)`..Please give this a try

Comment: If your Ajax call view is called `login.php` and is put in `resources/views/` try to rename that as `login.blade.php`. The problem is that you are using balde syntax: `{{ url('/dashboard/login') }}` in a non blade view. As a result you are not printing the correct URL, but the blade command as a string, and because of that you are making an HTTP request to: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/{{ url('/dashboard/login')` which gets encoded by JavaScript because it contains some special characters. You would then obtain: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/%7B%7B%20url('/dashboard/login')%20%7D%7D`

Comment: @ViperTecPro Thanks for your answer, but I don't know why, in non framework PHP I have to do json_encode(). But in Laravel, the response is always json. The first time I tried to encode to json, it get error. If not json, the android apps will not work, and API is already online and used by our user.

Comment: @mdexp Wow problem solved. I tried to ajax API and it get response. My login function is indeed error, but at least right now the url not encoded. Do I always have to write blade between file name and file type?

Comment: If you use the blade syntax, yes! Otherwise Laravel won't parse the blade commands and these will remains as normal strings. I posted my comment as an answer so you can mark your question as solved

Comment: @mdexp Thanks for the answer. Needs to learn more about Laravel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your Ajax call view is called `login.php` and is put in `resources/views/` try to rename that file as `login.blade.php`

The problem is that you are using blade syntax: `{{ url('/dashboard/login') }}` in a non blade view.

As a result Laravel isn't parsing that file and you are not printing the correct URL, but the blade command as a string.

Because of that you are making an HTTP request to: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/{{ url('/dashboard/login')` which gets encoded by the browser because it contains some special characters in the url.

You would then obtain: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/%7B%7B%20url('/dashboard/login')%20%7D%7D`

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass CSRF token along with your request.
Also Your blade syntax seems not working properly maybe your ajax request is not in blade file

```
$.ajax({
  url: "{{ url('/dashboard/login') }}",
  headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': '{{ csrf_token() }}'},
  method: "post",
  data: $(this).serialize(),
  success: function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  }
});
```

Comment: I did that, but it shows error in console like this `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`. Here is the link with that error looks like (http://127.0.0.1:8000/dashboard/%7B%7B%20url('/dashboard/login')%20%7D%7D)